# What if onAttach() is not overridden inside the fragment code?

Tags: android

According to fragment lifecycle `onAttach()` is called before `onCreate()` so that it assigns hosting activity to the fragment. So, I wanted to know what if it is not overridden. Does a default definition for all the fragment callbacks already exists?

Comment: you simply don't have to override it.

Comment: "According to fragment lifecycle onAttach() is called before onCreate() so that it assigns hosting activity to the fragment" what about this? @VladMatvienko

Comment: nothing new. `you simply don't have to override it.`

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.app.Activity)):

> **void onAttach (Activity activity)**

> called once the fragment is associated with its activity. This method was deprecated in API level
> 23. Use onAttach(Context) instead.
>
> If you override this method you must call through to the superclass
> implementation.
>
> **void onAttach (Context context)**
>
> Called when a fragment is first attached to its context. onCreate(Bundle) will be called after this.

This is a lifecyle design for the fragment. There is nothing wrong when you don't override the method.

**Does a default definition for all the fragment callbacks already exists?**

No, you need to create the fragment callback by yourself. `onAttach()` method is usually overriden to make sure the parent activity of the fragment is implementing the fragment callback. Something like this (read more at [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate)):

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

When the parent activity is not implementing `OnHeadlineSelectedListener`, the application will crash and throwing `must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener`. Hence it will preventing you introducing a logic error in your code.

---

#### UPDATE

**What the purpose of `onAttach()`?**

> According to fragment lifecycle onAttach() is called before onCreate()
> so that it assigns hosting activity to the fragment.

What the meaning of that actually?

Simple answer: It's a lifecyle of Fragment where we can know when the Fragment has been attached to it's parent activity.

***More details:***

From the the following [source code of `onAttach()`](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#L1563):

```
/**
 * Called when a fragment is first attached to its context.
 * {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} will be called after this.
 */
@CallSuper
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    mCalled = true;
    final Activity hostActivity = mHost == null ? null : mHost.getActivity();
    if (hostActivity != null) {
        mCalled = false;
        onAttach(hostActivity);
    }
}

/**
 * @deprecated Use {@link #onAttach(Context)} instead.
 */
@Deprecated
@CallSuper
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mCalled = true;

}
```

We will see nothing except the documentation about our previous question and
`mHost`.

on the source code of Fragment at https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java#L435, we can know that the `mhost` is actually a `FragmentHostCallback`:

```
// Activity this fragment is attached to.
FragmentHostCallback mHost;
```

But if we scanning through all the source code Fragment, we won't get any clue where the `mhost` is initialized.

We know that from the Fragment lifecyle diagram that the lifecyle is start when the fragment is added:

[image]

Programatically, we add the Fragment with:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Checking the [FragmentManager source code at line 1200 to 1229](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java#L1220) from method `moveToState()`:

```
void moveToState(Fragment f, int newState, int transit, int transitionStyle,
            boolean keepActive) {
}
```

we have the following code:

```
f.mHost = mHost;
f.mParentFragment = mParent;
f.mFragmentManager = mParent != null
        ? mParent.mChildFragmentManager : mHost.getFragmentManagerImpl();

// If we have a target fragment, push it along to at least CREATED
// so that this one can rely on it as an initialized dependency.
if (f.mTarget != null) {
    if (mActive.get(f.mTarget.mIndex) != f.mTarget) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + f
                + " declared target fragment " + f.mTarget
                + " that does not belong to this FragmentManager!");
    }
    if (f.mTarget.mState < Fragment.CREATED) {
        moveToState(f.mTarget, Fragment.CREATED, 0, 0, true);
    }
}

dispatchOnFragmentPreAttached(f, mHost.getContext(), false);
f.mCalled = false;
f.onAttach(mHost.getContext());
if (!f.mCalled) {
    throw new SuperNotCalledException("Fragment " + f
            + " did not call through to super.onAttach()");
}
if (f.mParentFragment == null) {
    mHost.onAttachFragment(f);
} else {
    f.mParentFragment.onAttachFragment(f);
}
```

Now we know that `mHost` and `onAttach()` of Fragment is initialized and called by the `FragmentManager`.

Comment: "According to fragment lifecycle onAttach() is called before onCreate() so that it assigns hosting activity to the fragment. " what about this? Can you tell me the actual purpose of onAttach() ?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens if you don't call OnAttach(). It is a lifecycle method provided to you if want to do something when the fragment is attached to its activity or context.

However, the fragment class does have a default implementation of OnAttach (which doesn't do anything). If you are curious, check out the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/Fragment.java).

Comment: I would also like to know why onclicklisteners cannot be attached to onattach?

Comment: I am not sure about your question. Click listeners are attached to UI controls such as buttons. They cannot be attached to lifecycle methods.

Comment: @Aditya the views are instantiated during onCreateView, so they are null when onAttach is called.

Comment: @HeikkiMaenpaa Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JaysonChacko I meant to Buttons when attached the listeners not working.