# Android Fragment OnAttach method

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android development and have a question about `OnAttach(Context context)` method. As far as I understand you override `OnAttach` method in the class that you extend Fragment and what it basically does is it attaches the fragment to the `Activity(Context)` that gets passed as a parameter. However, in a lot of example codes I've seen on the internet, people create an interface with methods that the main Activity needs to implement and in `OnAttach` method, they typecast context as the interface for ex)

```
public class exampleFragment extends Fragment{

exampleFragmentListener activityCommander;

public interface exampleFragmentListener{
    public void someMethod(String top, String bot);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        activityCommander = (exampleFragmentListener)context;

    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());

    }
}
```

What I don't get is this piece of code :

```
activityCommander = (exampleFragmentListener)context;
```

What's the purpose of typecasting context as `exampleFragmentListener?` Why would we typecast our **main activity** to **fragment?** Why can't the main activity just implement the `interface/implement` interface methods? Thank you in advance.

Comment: i think you can refer this answer, it will solve your query
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37031546/4980791

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we want a fragment to communicate with an Activity we use a interface. Now suppose if there are 2 Activities which host the same Fragment, and at runtime we don't know from which activity is the fragment is currently. That is the reason we use `onAttach()`. The `Context` provided to us in the parameter is the context of the Activity which is hosting it. So once we have the casted instance, we can use that to communicate with the activity.

Comment: so for each fragment, you would only have one Listener(interface), correct?

Comment: Yes, there will only be one interface which will be used to communicate with the activity, who is hosting the fragment.

Comment: But, it is not mandatory to only have one interface, you can have hundreds of them too. But, why create 100s when that work can be done with only one interface.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of Fragment to Activity communication:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Now the fragment can deliver messages and **commuticate** to the activity by calling the `onArticleSelected()` method (or other methods in the interface) using the `mCallback` instance of the OnHeadlineSelectedListener interface. So basically it's for callbacks

Comment: Check this out https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using the `onAttach` with the following code:

```
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try{
        activityCommander = (exampleFragmentListener)context;

    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString());

    }
}
```

simply is to make a dead contract of Activity and Fragment. Whenever the contract is not obeyed by the Activity, both the Activity and Fragment will be dead. Both of them will die by throwing the exception.

For `onAttach` details, please read my previous answer: [What if onAttach() is not overridden inside the fragment code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336201/what-if-onattach-is-not-overridden-inside-the-fragment-code/46336837#46336837)

Answer (score 0):

Add This on your Fragemnt

```
Activity activity;
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = context instanceof Activity ? (Activity) context : null;
}
```

Then change **getContext()** , **getActivity()** , **requireActivity()** or **requireContext()** with **activity**